# Getting variable undefined though it is declared globaly

Tags: javascript

```
function begin(firstName){
firstName = document.getElementById('name').value;
var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
console.log(firstName);
if (firstName == ""){
    alert("please enter a name here");
    return;
}
if (age == ""){
    alert("please enter your age here");
    return;
}
if(0 < age && age < 9){
    location.href = "toys.html";
    return;
}
if(10 < age && age < 16){
    location.href = "phones.html";
    return;
}
else{
    location.href = "cars.html";
}};
`table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].childNodes[1];
row = table.childNodes[2];
price =[table.childNodes[2].childNodes[3].innerHTML.substr(1),table.childNodes[4].childNodes[3].innerHTML.substr(1), table.childNodes[6].childNodes[3].innerHTML.substr(1)];
amount = [table.childNodes[2].childNodes[7].innerHTML.substr(1), table.childNodes[4].childNodes[7].innerHTML.substr(1), table.childNodes[6].childNodes[7].innerHTML.substr(1)];`
function update(){
console.log(firstName);
q1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity1').value);
q2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity2').value);
q3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity3').value);
if(isNaN(q3) == true){
    q3 = 0;
}
if(isNaN(q2) == true){
    q2 = 0;
}
if(isNaN(q1) == true){
    q1 = 0;
}
x = q1 + q2 + q3;
var amount1 = document.getElementById('amount1').innerHTML = "$" + price[0] * q1;
    amount2 = document.getElementById('amount2').innerHTML = "$" + price[1] * q2;
    amount3 = document.getElementById('amount3').innerHTML = "$" + price[2] * q3;
    n = parseInt(price[0]) * q1 + parseInt(price[1]) * q2  + parseInt(price[2]) * q3;
document.getElementById('totalAmount').innerHTML = "$" + n;
table.childNodes[8].childNodes[5].innerHTML = x;}
```

The variable firstName keeps coming up as undefined when the script moves to the next page, i thought i could use the variable in another function because it was declared globally but for some reason it keeps coming back undefined.

Comment: why do you think it was *declared globally*?

Comment: Variables are not remembered from page to page, but you can use a HTML 5 web storage to do that. Also what global variables are you talking about?

Comment: i read that within a function `variable = x;` is global and `var variable = x;` would be local, also i tried declaring it outside the function but i need the begin function to read the result after the user has typed it in.

Comment: because you pass it in as an argument and you name it as a parameter, it is localized to the function  (e.g., `function begin(firstName)`); if you name that *firstName* something else, or refer to it as `window.firstName` inside the function, you'll be using the global

Comment: Its the firstName variable thats giving me problems, and would it not save from page to page as its all in one script?

Comment: Variables that are parameters in functions are local. Also as I already noted it's not saved because when you move to another page everything from the last page is not remembered unless it's stored in web storage or in a cookie.

Comment: even with `begin();` i still get the same error

Comment: As Spencer says, Variables are not remembered from page to page. another way of passing them is as an argument on the url

Comment: Or you can pass it as an argument on the url

Comment: You should create a [__minimal, complete, and verifiable example__](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want us to be able to help you.